# Underlying provider failed in connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am getting the error of

> "underline provider failed in connection string"

also I am using the local db file in my project,for local it is working when I change the LOCAL DB to my Live IP it gives me error*

```
    <add name="dbEntities1"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.databse.csdl|res://*/Models.databse.ssdl|res://*/Models.databse.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=<SomeIP>;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\databse.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Please help in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "underline provider"?

Comment: @Tim, perhaps he means "Underlying"?

Comment: yes @tim wrongly written by me any solution from your end

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not modified your connection string it's incorrect. `<someip>` isn't valid.

Otherwise try to open the connection manually and see what error you get:

```
var conStr = "data source=<SomeIP>;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\databse.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True;";
var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
connection.Open();
```